# Como generar la ruta correcta en laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, laravel-8

Estoy hecha un lio con las rutas de Laravel, ya que he visto muchos modos de hacerlas y al final no se si llego a comprender como funcionan.

Tengo el siguiente controlador (VentaController.php)

En el que tengo estas funciónes:

```
public function mercadillo()
    {
        $ventasMercadillo =Venta::latest()->simplePaginate(5);
    //print_r($ventasMercadillo);

        return view('Market',compact('ventasMercadillo'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

public function mercadilloShow(Venta $ventasMercadillo)
    {
        return view('mercadilloShow',compact('ventasMercadillo'));
    }
```

La funcion de mercadillo() es lo que se muestra en la página "index" en esta ruta:

```
Route::get('/mercadillo', [VentaController::class, 'mercadillo']);
```

Si quiero mostrar desde mi página /mercadillo el id de cada producto  como se realizaría esta ruta, usando la función mercadilloShow()??

He probado sin exito:

```
Route::get('/mercadilloShow', [VentaController::class, 'mercadilloShow']);
Route::resource('mercadilloShow', VentaController::class);
```

La url con la que me he intentado dirigir desde el archivo mercadillo ha sido:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('mercadilloShow',$venta->id) }}">Ver</a>
```

el fichero al que se dirige se llama mercadilloShow.blade.php como puedo hacer correctamente la ruta y la url para poder ver el id de cada producto?

Comment: mm creo que lo entiendo mas o menos, me podrías poner un ejemplo porfavor? nose muy bien como crear después la url para entrar ahi tampoco y nose muy bien como funciona el tema de donde pone user iria mercadilloShow?

Comment: Te falto el `->name('mercadilloShow')` y `Route::get('/mercadilloShow/{ventasMercadillo}'`, segun la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes). Recuerda que al usar `route()` se tiene que tener en tu ruta `->name`, y para para pasar un valor, se tiene que tener en tu ruta esto`/{var}` , donde `var` seria el nombre de tu variable

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! eso era, estaba ya mareada voy a ver la documentacion